# How to query SELECT WHERE...BETWEEN two variables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this code to filter product prices, but I am still confused about using two variables for a `SELECT WHERE...BETWEEN` query. This is code:

```
$min=$this->input->post('minValue');
$max=$this->input->post('maxValue');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('msproduct');
$this->db->where('ProductPrize BETWEEN $min AND $max');
$query = $this->db->get();
data['product']=$query->result();
$this->load->view("user/product/product_filter",$data);
```

And I get this error:

> Unknown column '$min' in 'where clause'

Comment: try  `$this->db->where("ProductPrize BETWEEN $min AND $max");`

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe because `$min` and `$max` variables are not evaluated in

```
$this->db->where('ProductPrize BETWEEN $min AND $max');
```

Change that to

```
$this->db->where("ProductPrize BETWEEN $min AND $max");
```

Notice the quote. `'` does not evaluate php variables inside but `"` does evaluate them

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$min=$this->input->post('minValue');
$max=$this->input->post('maxValue');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('msproduct');
$this->db->where('ProductPrize >=', $min);
$this->db->where('ProductPrize <=', $max);
$query = $this->db->get();
data['product']=$query->result();
$this->load->view("user/product/product_filter",$data);
```